# Как связать уже созданный репозиторий с локальным

Tags: git

Всем привет,мне нужно Иницилизировать git-репозиторий на гите где проект уже создан, как  его связать с локальным? Подскажите
Много чего нашел в интернете,но немного не понимаю в каком порядке все это делать

Comment: Вы нигде не спутали гит и гитхаб? Потому что если у вас есть пустой (реально пустой, даже без ридми) репозиторий на гитхабе, он должен вам показать инструкцию по связыванию с существующим.

Comment: `$ man git-remote`, затем `$ git remote add имя ссылка`.

Answer (score 3):

для того, чтобы «привязать» к своему git-хранилищу другое, служит команда `remote add`:

```
$ git remote add произвольное-имя url-хранилища
```

для первого (и часто единственного) из «привязанных» хранилищ обычно принято давать имя `origin`

---

чтобы просмотреть список имён уже привязанных хранилищ, служит команда `remote show`:

```
$ git remote show
```

чтобы посмотреть информацию о хранилище, служит та же команда, но с указанием имени:

```
$ git remote show -n имя
```

опция `-n` служит для того, чтобы не устанавливать при выполнении команды связь с самим хранилищем, а использовать только локально кэшированную информацию.

Answer (score 1):

Вы когда работаете с git-репозиторием, он просто смотрит в конфигурацию этого репозитория в папке `.git`, а там может быть что-то вроде:

```
$ cat ./.git/config
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@172.17.1.100:someproject
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

Если у вас пустой репозиторий, просто допишите в конфиг то что вам нужно - например секцию `[remote "origin"]` из примера, только **с вашим логином, хостом и проектом**, разумеется, и git станет думать что это пустой репозиторий, связанный с удаленным (remote) репозиторием

Answer (score 0):

`git remote show` - показать ветки удаленного репозитория

Пример для репозитория на гитхабе(у вас репозиторий может быть кроме GitHub на другом сервере):

```
git remote add <имя_вашей_ветки> протокол@github.com:пользователь/BBBB.git
```

Пример:

```
git remote add короткое_имя_вашей_ветки git@github.com:имя_пользователя/BBBB.git
```

короткое_имя_вашей_ветки — любое имя которое вы выберите. Смотрите документацию git по выбору имен.

Протокол - https://, git, SSH.
Git может работать с четырьмя сетевыми протоколами для передачи данных: локальный, HTTPS, Secure Shell (SSH) и Git.
имя_пользователя — короткое имя пользователя зарегистрированного на гитхабе

Answer (score 0):

```
git remote add репка https://github.com/ты/репка.git
git push --set-upstream репка master
git push репка master --force
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]